# Get Praat version in script

Tags: praat

Is there a command in the Praat scripting language that will get the user's current Praat version? The reason I ask is that I want to distribute a script that uses vectors, but since vectors were only introduced in the last year, some users won't be able to run the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line echoes the script version: `echo 'praatVersion$'`.

If you want to check for the current version you sound do:

```
versionPraat$ = left$(praatVersion$, (rindex(praatVersion$, ".")-1));
versionPraat = 'versionPraat$' #convert string to numeric

if versionPraat < 6
   exit Please download the most recent version of Praat.
endif
```

I stole this from a script written by Chun Chan.

Answer (score 1):

[DazedAndConfused](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/21292/dazedandconfused) had the basic answer: `praatVersion$` gets you a string with the version. If you're looking for a way to get the major/minor/build numbers in a way that's robust to Praat's versioning convention (where 6.0, 6.0.01, and 6.1.17alpha are all valid version numbers), use the following:

```
dot1 = index(praatVersion$, ".")
majorVers = number(left$(praatVersion$, dot1-1))
nonMajorVers$ = right$(praatVersion$, length(praatVersion$)-dot1)
dot2 = index(nonMajorVers$, ".")
if dot2 > 0
    minorVers = number(left$(nonMajorVers$, dot2-1))
    buildVers = number(replace_regex$(right$(nonMajorVers$, length(nonMajorVers$)-dot2), "[^0-9]", "", 0))
else
    minorVers = number(replace_regex$(nonMajorVers$, "[^0-9]", "", 0))
endif
```